# Integer Reverse fails 4 cases

Tags: java, integer, reverse

For some reason this code fails only 4 cases, namely when passed 1534236469 it is supposed to return 0 but returns 2147483647.

Edit: The code is supposed to reverse the values that its passed. If given 123 it needs to return 321.

```
class Solution {
    public int reverse(int x) {
        int val = x;
        if(val >= (Math.pow(2,31))||val<= Math.pow(-2,31)){
            return 0;
        }
        int sum = 0;
        String str = ""+Math.abs(x);
        
        char[] c = str.toCharArray();
        int power = c.length-1;
        for(int i = c.length-1;i>=0;i--){
            
            int j = Integer.parseInt(""+c[i]);
            sum+=(Math.pow(10,power)*j);
            power--;
        }
        if(x<0){
            sum=sum*-1;
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just use Integer.MAX_VALUE and Integer.MIN_VALUE rather than using Math.Pow and magic numbers?

Comment: To get the lowest digit of an int and remove it from the int, ``int d = x % 10``, then ``x = x / 10``. 105 means d = 5 and x = 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’ve got an undetected `int` overflow.

`Math.pow(2, 31)` is 2 147 483 648. Similarly `Math.pow(-2, 31)` is -2 147 483 648. The value you try to reverse, 1 534 236 469, is comfortably within these bounds. So you method skips the `if` statement at the beginning where it might have returned 0.

It then tries reverse the number. The reverse would have been 9 646 324 351. However this number is way too large to fit into a 32 bits signed `int`. What Java does is it discards the frontmost bits (the most significant bits). This is bound to give us a nonsense result. Which happens to be 2 147 483 647 (the largest number that *can* fit into an `int`).

The solution? One way is to calculate the sum in a `long` rather than an `int`. This will ensure that you have no overflow. If you want to return 0 in case of `int` overflow, then at the end check that the sum is less than 2^32, and if not, return 0 instead.